# Seach function in Access syntax error: missing a comma in query expression

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem while I'm working on a search function at Windows Access that allowed me to search after 3 things. In this case, it's first name, Last name and CPR. Now the CPR means it's a serial of unique numbers to each users on my Database.

It started as a macro then I changed it into VBA code because I want it to have the option to search after 3.

when it's in macro, it can only find 2 things because the limit for write characters in macro is 255, which is the reason that I changed it to VBA code which the characters limit should be unlimited.

Ah, I almost forgot, the code's in danish, but I think the basic functions of the code is almost pretty much same everywhere so...

Here is the problem:

```
On Error GoTo SøgEfterFornavn_Err

    If (IsNull(Forms!Navigationsformular!NavigationUnderformular!SearchFor)) Then
        Beep
        Exit Function
    Else
        DoCmd.SetFilter "Søgnings forespørgelse", "[Fornavn] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Navigationsformular]![NavigationUnderformular]![SearchFor] & ""*"" Or [CPR] Like ""*"" & [Forms]![Navigationsformular]![NavigationUnderformular]![SearchFor] & ""*"" Or [Efternavn] Like ""*"" & [Formularer]![Navigationsformular]![NavigationUnderformular]![SearchFor] & ""*"", """"
        Exit Function
    End If


SøgEfterFornavn_Exit:
    Exit Function

SøgEfterFornavn_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume SøgEfterFornavn_Exit
```

It keeps saying that "Syntax error: missing a comma in query expression" 
which I don't understand? Did I do something wrong or?

Comment: You can make your life a lot easier by using single quotes for SQL that you create in VBA: `"[Fornavn] Like '*" & [Forms]![Navigationsformular]![NavigationUnderformular]![SearchFor] & "*' Or [CPR] Like '*" & [Forms]!...` -- No more double and triple quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to put some quote signs ("):

```
DoCmd.SetFilter "Søgnings forespørgelse", "[Fornavn] Like ""*""" & [Forms]![Navigationsformular]![NavigationUnderformular]![SearchFor] & """*"" Or [CPR] Like ""*""" & [Forms]![Navigationsformular]![NavigationUnderformular]![SearchFor] & """*"" Or [Efternavn] Like ""*""" & [Formularer]![Navigationsformular]![NavigationUnderformular]![SearchFor] & ""*""", """"
```

You probably forgot them because you need to put the quote character twice  to have it in the string (as escape character).

Comment: Just to clarify... the missing " was at the end of the last ""*"" section.  Otherwise without knowing they might miss it as it looks like a blur anyhow :)

Comment: Actually they were missing after and before the others (`""*""`) also.

Comment: ah, now it's sort of working. There're no more syntax error, but "Compile error: External name not defined" showed up instead. Hmm... any idea?

Comment: To which name does it refer to? Have you checked all the column, form, and field names?

Comment: It's `Forms!Mainform!Subform1.Form!ControlName` i.e. `[Forms]![Navigationsformular]![NavigationUnderformular].Form![SearchFor]`. Here is a good reference: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: @Agold: Yes, I have checked all of them. Nothing looks really out of place, so I'm more or less clueless.

Comment: @Andre451: Well, the error is still there after change the refer. But thanks for the link anyway!

Comment: Try to debug it by doing a query directly, and put the values which you put in the form. If then query doesn't give you good results, try to do just parts of the query. If the query does work then check if your form is correct, and if you really got the correct values.

Comment: @agold: Well, the query works. The form is correct, however I'm kinda confuse with the correct values. Weird enough the macro version of it works by giving the correct values when the VBA version don't.